# Insserv error installing cherokee on fresh Debian squeeze

Tags: debian, cherokee

Steps:

1) Installed Debian 6.0 i386 minimal

2) apt-get update, apt-get upgrade

3) apt-get install cherokee

4) the following error:

https://gist.github.com/964452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would *seem* vzquota installed a broken initscript previously, and setting up cherokee now fails because of it. Can you remove the package vzquota and try again with `apt-get -f install`? If you can't remove it try moving /etc/init.d/vzquota to some other place temporarily and run `apt-get -f install` to try to finish configuring cherokee.

By the way this is probably good material for a bug report: http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting.

Comment: But is the init script there?

Comment: I filed this bug report:
http://code.google.com/p/cherokee/issues/detail?id=1198

Comment: vzquota is not installed but yes the init script is there. Removing the script allowed apt-get to configure cherokee successfully. Thanks :)

Comment: So did you try the workaround (moving it temporarily elsewhere)?

Comment: Yes that worked ((ninja)edited comment above)